# Using Select query with more than 20 table joins or view with the same query in frequent REST GET by ID API

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have a REST GET API to get a record from database table which had around join with 25 tables and have to fetch few Columns from each of 25 tables.

So querying by

```
SELECT tableA.id, tableB.name, tableC.data, tabled.eid....table20.aid FROM tableA 
LEFT JOIN tableB on .... 
LEFT JOIN tableC on....
25 join statements 
WHERE a.id = runtime Parameter
```

Or by

Creating a database **view** with the same query but with a stored procedure to pass runtime Parameter to view in SQL server.

Which type of querying is better at performance as this API calls are more.?

Comment: You said a few columns but your example shows `SELECT *` (all columns). I expect no performance difference with parameterized query in a proc versus a parameterized query against a view.

Comment: Shouldn't make any difference. Just don't use select * and check the execution plan for possible indexes to improve performance.

Comment: So long as you aren't selecting all columns, a straight forward query might be good enough. However, a view would allow you to provide explicit index hints. A procedure would allow you to build partial results in temporary tables to force a particular approach to building the final result, which can be particularly useful if the search criteria is complicated.

Comment: Another approach might involve caching in some other layer of your application.